# d3.js Fill area between to diagonals

Tags: d3.js, area, diagonal

I would to imitate the pink filled elemets in the image. I think those are two diagonals. But I dont know how to fill the area between them.

[image]

Any help, I would appreciate it too much! 
This is the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <body>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
    </style>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Chart</h1>
    <div class="chart"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
  var links = [{source: {x:0,y:0}, target: {x:200,y:200},x:0,y:0},
               {source: {x:0,y:0}, target: {x:170,y:200},x:0,y:0}
              ]

  var canvas = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .append("g");


        var linksContainer = canvas.append("g").attr("class","linksContainer")
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .source(function(d) { return {"x":d.source.x, "y":d.source.y}; })
                .target(function(d) { return {"x":d.target.x, "y":d.target.y};})
                .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });


        var link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(links)
                .enter()
                  .append("path")
                  .attr("class", "link")
                  .attr("d", diagonal);

                  var line = linksContainer.append("line")
                          .attr("x1", 170)
                          .attr("y1", 200)
                          .attr("x2", 200)
                          .attr("y2", 200)
                          .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                          .attr("stroke", "black");
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1046712

Comment: Hi @meetamit I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. I attached some html/js code to give you a better idea what I am looking for. I would like fill the area between the diagonals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.svg.diagonal()` produces a String representing an SVG path description. In your case, the two paths Strings are

```
var path1 = diagonal(links[0]);// "M0,0C0,100 200,100 200,200"
```

and

```
var path2 = diagonal(links[1]);// "M0,0C0,100 170,100 170,200"
```

Your code currently assigns each of them to the `d` attribute of a `<path class=".link" d="...">`.

Instead, you need to make just a single `<path>` with a filled (hence closed) path string that is a combination of those two strings.

```
var shape = path1 + path2;// But not quite...
```

It turns out that you can't simply concat those two strings. One thing you need to do is replace the `M` — which picks up and moves the pen to a new point (thus interrupting the closed-ness of the shape) — with an `L`, which draws a line to that new point:

```
var path2 = diagonal(links[1]).replace(/^M/, 'L');// "L0,0C0,100 170,100 170,200"
```

That gives you this:

```
var shape = path1 + path2;// "M0,0C0,100 170,100 170,200 L0,0C0,100 170,100 170,200"
```

However, the sub-path `...170,200 L0,0...` incorrectly connects the end of `path1` to the start of `path2`. To correct this, you need to reverse `path2` by swapping between the link's start and end points:

```
var links = [ {source: {x:0,y:0}, target: {x:200,y:200},x:0,y:0},
// instead of {source: {x:0,y:0}, target: {x:170,y:200},x:0,y:0}]
              {source: {x:170,y:200}, target: {x:0,y:0},x:0,y:0}]
```

Finally, this might not make a difference visually, but for correctness, you should close the path, using the `Z` directive:

```
var shape = path1 + path2 + 'Z';

// Apply `shape` to a single path element:
var path = linksContainer.append('path')
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", shape);
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk0gyor8/2/).

Answer (score -1):

The picture shown is actually a chord diagram layout.

You can learn how to use it here
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout

Diagonals are different shapes that are used for tree diagrams

Comment: Sorry Andres, chord diagram layout doesnot worked for me. Beacuse y just need a part of it. And chrod diagram is given as a single thing.  
The answer of @meetamit is exactly what I was looking for.